# what file to change for this to remove compare block?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, address, compare

when going to www.domain.com/customer/address/edit/id/1/

where one can edit their address

for some reason there is a block compare in left sidebar

what file do i need to edit to remove this?

Thanks

Carlo

In my layout.xml (app/design/frontend/mythemepackage/default/layout/local.xml)

i have this:

```
 <!-- CUSTOMER ACCOUNT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% -->
<customer_account>

    <reference name="left">
        <!-- Remove cart from the left column -->
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action>

        <!-- Remove Compare block, it is already inserted in DEFAULT section -->
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
    </reference>

</customer_account>
```

the default section it refers to is this i guess in same file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Left ====================================================================== -->
    <reference name="left">
        <remove name="left.newsletter"/> <!-- Moved newsletter to the footer -->
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>left.permanent.callout</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>left.reports.product.viewed</name></action>
      <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
        <!--  <block type="reports/product_compared" name="right.reports.product.compared" template="reports/product_compared.phtml" />
       <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="left.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
       <block type="wishlist/customer_sidebar" name="wishlist_sidebar" as="wishlist" template="wishlist/sidebar.phtml"/>
       <block type="poll/activePoll" name="right.poll">
           <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/active.phtml</template><type>poll</type></action>
           <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/result.phtml</template><type>results</type></action>
       </block>
       <block type="tag/popular" name="tags_popular" template="tag/popular.phtml"/>
       <block type="paypal/logo" name="paypal.partner.right.logo" template="paypal/partner/logo.phtml"/> -->

        <action method="unsetChild"><name>tags_popular</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>right.reports.product.compared</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>right.reports.product.viewed</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>wishlist</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>sale.reorder.sidebar</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>right.poll</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>paypal.partner.right.logo</name></action>
    </reference>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not using your own module, you should create a local layout file at location `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout/local.xml` and assuming you are seeing the compare block which is added by default you should add the following into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account>
        <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
    </customer_account>
</layout>
```

However this does mean that you will not be able to re-use the block name (`catalog.compare.sidebar`) if you use `<remove>`.  If you want to re-use the same block name within the layout then use the following instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="left">
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
</layout>
```

Comment: Jonathan, when i add that xml to app/design/frontend/[package]/[mytheme]/layout it messed up the whole site... i guess that has something to do with layout version? (that is not in local.xml file that is in package/default

Comment: If `local.xml` does not exist then you can just create it, it will be automatically found so you add the `local.xml` file within the layout directory with the above contents if that's not what you have done.

Comment: yes i have done that but it is as it doesn't read the main local.xml anymore

app/design/frontend/[package]/[mytheme]/layout.xml

Point is that [mytheme] has default and subs in it...

default already has this file (with all kinds of configuration in it) so when i add another xml file in the sub i use it does not load the one in default i guess

Comment: If you already have `local.xml` just add the `<customer_account>` section above into your existing layout file...

Comment: I checked and that is already in that file... so for some reason there is another instance? It has this comment: <!-- Remove Compare block, it is already inserted in DEFAULT section -->

Comment: Add your `local.xml` into the question so we can see what you are describing.

Comment: i added the parts in that local.xml file

Comment: You don't show a layout handle in the first section but you are both adding an removing the block in what you have posted.  You should remove the block as per my answer and only add it to the layout for those layout handles that require it rather than using the `<default>` handle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18733/discussion-between-carlo-and-jonathan-hussey).

Comment: To be fair, I think I've given you all the information you need - it is after all just removing a block from the layout...  So not going into chat.

Comment: If that's how you want to do it - really not a great solution though.

Comment: i know but i couldnt get the other one working... got lost in the process unfortunately

Comment: couldn't let it go and i got some result...

when i change this

<customer_account>

        <reference name="left">
            <!-- Remove cart from the left column -->
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action>

            <!-- Remove Compare block, it is already inserted in DEFAULT section -->
            <action method="unsetChild">     <name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>

        </reference>

    </customer_account>


to this

Comment: <customer_account>

        <reference name="left">
            <!-- Remove cart from the left column -->
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action>

            <!-- Remove Compare block, it is already inserted in DEFAULT section -->
            <action method="unsetChild">
      <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
        </reference>

    </customer_account>

Comment: than the block is gone... i this also a valid and good way?

Comment: You shouldn't have `<remove>` inside `<action method="unsetChild">`, just have remove as per my answer.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan... i did, but i copy/pasted to fast here... this is what i have: 

<customer_account>

        <reference name="left">
            <!-- Remove cart from the left column -->
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action>

            <!-- Remove Compare block, it is already inserted in DEFAULT section -->
      <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
        </reference>
    </customer_account>

now i have to try the same trick for the search result page right bar...

Comment: You don't need to use `<reference>` with `<remove>` it can go directly inside the `<customer_account> ` layout handle.

Comment: ok thanks... i changed it now. Thank you for your patience an helping me on this one. Appreciated it very much!

Comment: No worries, could you mark my answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<customer_address_edit>
<reference name="left">
 <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
</reference>
<customer_address_edit>
```

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2 add below lines in themes's default.xml file

> \app\design\frontend\default\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true"/>
```